# Problem : Subdomains redirecting to main domain , and all pages show 404 error , only root ' / ' is working

Tags: php, laravel, apache, hosting

My website was working fine , i did no changement and suddenly all subdomains are redirecting to the main domain , and all pages are returning an 404 error , only the root is working as it was .
My website is made with laravel and running on apache server .

Comment: Anything changed in the apache config?

Comment: Nothing changed , the .htaccess files are the same as before

Comment: simply means that if you facing error 404 then it's clear that it can not found the path. So kindly check your DNS zone especially A, CNAME record and check your subdomains path from the control panel.